# How to run code when a user logs out or is logged out automatically due to session timeout?

Tags: laravel

I would like to have a function along the lines of `onUserSessionEnd` where I can perform cleanup tasks relating to the user. How do I do that in Laravel?

There is a function `logout(Request $request)` in `Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers.php` - how do I execute code *after* this function is called?

Answer (score 0):

You can listen for events.

[Documentation regarding Laravel events.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/events#registering-events-and-listeners)

[List of Auth events in Laravel api.](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Auth/Events.html)

In your case you should probably use [Login](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Login.html) and [Logout](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Auth/Events/Logout.html) events.

[Brief guide regarding auth events.](https://darkghosthunter.medium.com/laravel-all-the-authentication-events-800165f69fb9)